# Element shows as removed in developer tools, but is still present visually in the page

Tags: javascript, css, brightcove

I have a Brightcove player and I want to change the play button to a pause button, when the player is paused.

This is the player:

```
<div style=\"position: relative; display: block; max-width: 1515px;\"><div style=\"padding-top: 50.77574047954866%;\"><video id=\"myPlayerID3\" ' +
            ' data-video-id=\"' + data3.videoId + '\" ' +
            ' data-account=\"' + data3.accountId + '\" ' +
            ' data-player=\"' + data3.playerId + '\" ' +
            ' data-embed=\"default\" class=\"video-js\" ' +
            ' controls></video>
```

And this is the styling of the button:

```
    #myPlayerID3 .vjs-big-play-button {
        display: block;
        background: url(myurl) 25% center/contain no-repeat;
        right:0px;
        left:10%;
        top:68%;
        bottom:0;
        position:absolute;
        border-radius: 0;
        width:10%;
        height: 12%;
    }
```

And this is the code that handles the pause event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var artist_video = document.querySelector("#artist_video");
    var artist_video_play_button = artist_video.querySelector(".vjs-big-play-button")
    videojs.getPlayer('myPlayerID3').on('pause',function(){
    artist_video_play_button.style.background = "url(myurl) 25% center/contain no-repeat";
    });
```

The code fires fine when the player is paused, but this happens:
[image]

The pause button appears, but the play button does not go away. And if I check the styles in developer tools, you can see that the "play" picture is marked as strikethrough (background property of `#myPlayerID3`), but it is still visible in the page:

[image]

If I uncheck the checkbox of the background style in developer tools, it goes away. Is this a rendering thing?

I've tried to remove the style like this

```
artist_video_play_button.removeAttribute("style");
```

or like this

```
artist_video_play_button.style.background = null;
```

But it did not work

Comment: instead of changing the image through JS, try it in css. i.e. on pause, add a class to the .vjs-big-play-button and in css add the background image to that class. See if that works

Comment: I just did this on pause: `artist_video_play_button.classList.add("paused");` and the `.paused` class has only this css style: `.paused { background: url(myurl) 25% center/contain no-repeat}` . It did not work. This time, not even the pause button appeared

Comment: In the dev tool, are you able to see the "paused" class with value?

Comment: I do not actually. I do not see this class added in the play button element.

Comment: even if I do `artist_video_play_button.remove();` the element is still there, it does not get removed

Comment: Check if artist_video_play_button is having the right dom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239907/discussion-between-tasos-and-jibin-jay).

Comment: The default style uses a font icon rather than a background image. It might be that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that brightcove spawns a button while dumping HTML code in the page and that button takes the classes of the div (which is also acting as the button) and therefore it's styles. The solution was to remove the button altogether, after brightcove spawned it's HTML stuff, meaning after `$(document).ready(function() =>{})`

In the end we decided to drop brightcove and switch to CDN and simple HTML5 `video` tags, because this concept of brightcove spawning HTML code while the page is rendering was introducing a considerable amount of problems with customization